# USB 2 to USB 3 speed

Tags: wireless-networking, router, usb, internet, smartphone

I read through some posts pertaining to my problem but did not find a 100% yes or no answer. So at the risk of sounding stupid, I will ask it and see what happens.
I have 1 gig up and down at my home fiber internet. But my computer has USB 2 ports and 1 HMDI port. I have purchased a USB 2 X ethernet RJ45 adapter so to hook to the router. The USB 2 port has a slower speed than the USB 3 so I am getting about 100 both ways as expected. The weakest link is the USB 2 plug. Regardless of what you do, the speed will never be faster that the USB 2. With all this said as expected you guys know this already. It actually is faster on wifi. Is there any way the USB 2 port can be made faster? I planned to do several projects 24/7 and need the bandwidth. If not then I have overkill and overpriced service.  I also plan to use a couple of old serviceless android phones with the micro receptacle and run them off the router or wifi. It appears I will need to go wifi with these phones as well. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And laptop does not have an ethernet port?!

Comment: `I am getting about 100 both ways as expected.` I suppose it's 100Mbps adapter instead of a Gigabit one? It could still help a bit to get a USB3/Gigabit one even if you plug it to USB2 host. (But yeah it'll at best be similar to some ac WiFi.)

Comment: I'll second what Tom Yan said. USB 2 is supposedly 480Mbps, but it has famously bad overhead, but even so, you should be able to get at least 200Mbps out of it. So if you're only getting 100Mbps (especially if you're getting about 94Mbps), then you're probably only doing 100Mbps Ethernet, not gigabit. Get a gigabit Ethernet adapter.

Comment: All the (USB2.0) adapters I've used many years ago were in fact 100Mbps. Coincidentally I've found one of those recently when cleaning up a drawer with a bunch of old stuff. Just a cheap unbranded device I no longer remember when or why I got it - probably some 12/15 years ago - with only a sticker saying "USB 2.0 to Fast Ethernet Adapter". It uses Realtek RTL8152 inside.